# ExpressionEngine file manager - default to thumbnail view

Tags: expressionengine

At the moment when you go to select an image inside an entry using the EE default file manager, the default view is 'show files as a list'.

Is there a way to show the thumbnail view as the default?

At this point I would be happy with a core hack.

I don't usually use the file manager for sites (much prefer Assets) but this client had a tight budget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wondered about doing this in the past as well - turns out it's pretty simple. Open up ee_filebrowser.js and search for the first instance of `a("#dir_choice").val()`. Immediately after that add this:

```
; a("#view_type").val('thumb').change();
```

Make sure you include the leading `;`.

I've only tested this in Safari but I can't see why it wouldn't work everywhere. Incidentally, [JS beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) makes this sort of thing infinitely easier.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't recommend hacking core for any reason and I suggest it should be avoided at all cost.**

With that said, I will provide what I've found out just the same.

Looks like the following files, in EE 2.5.3, are what you'd want to edit:

```
/themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/plugins/ee_filebrowser.js
/system/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php
```

I found these doing a file search in my text editor for `view_type` which was from the id of that dropdown. The javascript is minified so you'd probably want to [un-minify it](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and then rewrite the part which handles the switch. I'm not the best JS/jQuery person out there, and un-minified js makes it a bit harder too so, I won't offer any more than what I've found so far.

Consider pulling out the parts parts from the two files if you aren't great with js and maybe start a new post tagged accordingly.

Also note: there might be more to this than just those two files so consider this answer a start and nothing more.

Comment: I disagree - there are occasions when you NEED to hack the core. I mean even some of the bug tracker solutions involve editing core code (granted until a patch is released).

What's important is making sure you track such changes to core code if you are going to make a change like that.

Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: It's a disclaimer. Even in this case I'm sure you could find away to do this without hacking the core though, I understand at the end of the day you might not be paid for taking the long route (high road?) and just need to get the job done. It wasn't directed at you per se rather, to get people thinking before they go down that road. Documentation, GIT branches and anything which helps track these types of necessary "hacks" could have been another point brought to light vs my more strait edge suggestion.

Comment: for sure - if I remember correctly the guys at Devot-ee and Newism use GIT submodules when hacking the core.